# Catching an exception when indexing a list in Haskell

Tags: list, exception, haskell

```
getChar :: Int -> IO Char
getChar n = do   
    c <- getLine   
    return (c !! n)
```

The program must needs a number and a line and it will return char, but how do I catch exception, if the number is too big?

I tried like this but it doesnt seem to work

```
getChar n   
   = do    
       c <-getLine   
| n>=0 && n < b   
  = return c !! n    
| otherwise    
  = error "Too big number"    
where
  b = length c
```

This is not a homework, im trying to involve myself. Google didint give me useful answers
Couldn't implement catch in there. Examples?

Comment: Don't throw an exception. Guard against it by checking the index, then returning a `Maybe` value if it fails.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to restructure things a bit as you've got IO mixed up in something it doesn't have to be.  What about changing the signature to something like this?

```
getChar :: Int -> String -> Maybe Char
getChar n x | n < length x = Just (x !! n)
            | otherwise = Nothing
```

[Data.Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) allows you to indicate that you are either going to return something (e.g. the length is within range) or Nothing (the length isn't within range).  The function that calls `getChar` can then decide what to do with things.  [Data.Either](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Either.html) provides a way of returning an error message with an error instead.  From what I've seen (and I'm by no means an expert) exceptions are rarely used in Haskell, and choice types such as `Either` or `Maybe` are much more commonly used.

Now in the code that calls this, you can use pattern matching to see what happened e.g.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- getLine
  let z = getChar' 5 x
  case z of
      (Just z) -> print $ "The 5th character is " ++ show z
      Nothing -> print $ "The 5th character is out of range"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `drop` function to drop the first n characters of the line (`drop` will just give an empty result if there are fewer than n chars), and the `listToMaybe` function to turn a list to a Maybe (either Just c where c is the first element of the list, or Nothing if the list is empty):

```
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

getchar :: Int -> IO (Maybe Char)
getchar n = do
    line <- getLine
    return . listToMaybe . drop n $ line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getChar' :: Int -> IO Char
getChar' n = 
    do
            c <- getLine
            if (n < length c)
               then
                    return (c !! n)
               else
                    getChar' n
```

You can do something like above. This is just an example though. But, since you are a beginner, it is strongly recommended not to play with IO and Monads. You can come to it after you get familiarized with pure functional concepts.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for that
I tried smth like that but it didint work for me :P

Comment: but why can't I add
     return (c !! (ceiling n))     ?
or round

Comment: If n is an Int then (ceiling n) is not defined.  ceiling and round are  in the RealFrac type class which includes Double and Float but not Int.